# python tkinter how to find the closest item that is in a specific list with canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, find

i know how that you can find the closest item in canvas with the canvas.find_closest() method but i would like that it finds the closest item that follows a specific creteria like that it is in a list

for example:

```py
from tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=100)

item1=canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50)
item2=canvas.create_rectangle(30, 30, 80, 80)
item3=canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300)

list_of_items=[item1, item2]

def find_closest_item(event):
    item=canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", find_closest_item)
```

in this code i would like that if i click on item3 it wont find it because its not in the "list_of_items" and that it would find the closest after item3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any good way to do this. I can hack a solution by making a custom Canvas widget that keeps a separate area for finding things, that way I can define a `finditem` argument.

```
import tkinter as tk
from types import MethodType

class FindCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    """
    A type of Canvas where items can be exempted from find methods
    including find, find_above, find_all, find_below, find_closest,
    find_enclosed, find_overlapping, find_withtag
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.finder = tk.Canvas(master, **kwargs)
        # these methods need to be called in both instances
        for methodname in ("move", "delete", "coords", "dchars"):
            def func(self, *args, methodname=methodname, **kwargs):
                getattr(self.finder, methodname)(*args, **kwargs)
                return getattr(super(), methodname)(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(self, methodname, MethodType(func, self))
    def find(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.finder.find(*args, **kwargs)
    def _create(self, itemType, args, kw):
        kwargs = kw
        if not kw.pop("finditem", True):
            kwargs = dict(list(kw.items()) + [('state', 'hidden')]) # yes, I know about 3.9
        self.finder._create(itemType, args, kwargs)
        return super()._create(itemType, args, kw)

### DEMO use:

def find_closest_item(event):
    item=canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    lbl.config(text="Closest item is item number "+str(item))

root=tk.Tk()

canvas=FindCanvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
item1=canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50)
item2=canvas.create_rectangle(30, 30, 80, 80)
item3=canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300, finditem=False)
item4=canvas.create_oval(30, 300, 100, 400, finditem=False)
item5=canvas.create_rectangle(60, 340, 80, 380)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", find_closest_item)

lbl = tk.Label(root)
lbl.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

BTW, using `from tkinter import *` and `tk=Tk()` is very buggy,  unconventional and may break this code. Do it the standard way I showed.